# Wanted: a hint (not a walk-through) for the Trainyard level called A Barrel Roll

Tags: ios, trainyard

I've been playing [Trainyard](http://www.trainyard.ca/) on my iPhone.  I'm having fun.  But I've reached A Barrel Roll and I'm not getting past it.  I can get the cars down to two purple and two green but I don't have enough free space at that point to work out a merging pattern to get them down to one of each.  I started over and tried to work out a system of pre-merging the blues, reds and yellows but then I didn't have enough space to do a final merge.  And I don't really know what to try next.

There are places I can watch a walk-through and places that will just show me a winning screen.  And I could move on.  but if anyone here plays that game and can give me just a nudge in the right direction, I'd rather go that route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that one is difficult.

You just want a hint, so it's hard to say exactly how to provide a good answer to your question.  But here goes.

### Hint #1

My solution involves first getting 4 Green and 4 Purples, not pre-merging the primary colors.

### Hint #2

Split them up so the Greens go to one side and the Purples go to the other.

### Hint #3

Focus on either Green or Purple side for your solution.  the other side can be a mirror image (or rotation) once you work out a solution for the other side.  You only need half the map.

### Hint #4

My solution involves 3 merges each: 2 on the top merge, then 2 on the bottom merge, then the results merge.

### Hint #5

Your first 2 merging stations (to go from 4 to 3 and 3 to 2) should only take 4 tiles total - a small loop that goes away from and then comes back to a track.  This is because the trains are only 2 tiles apart.

### Hint #6

All 3 of my merges on each side are within 1 time increment of one another (a time increment defined as how long it takes 1 train to move 1 tile).

### Hint #7

I'm running out of hints here without showing you a picture.

Comment: Thanks!  I don't have time to try it now but I'm making a point of not reading the hints so that I can try it out with as little info as possible.  That kind of staged response is perfect!